# Issue with PulseAudio When Configuring for Multiple Users [Ubuntu 22.04]

Tags: pulseaudio

I've got PulseAudio set up on my machine, working without any issues for the user `windowsxp` when accessed via `RDP` and `PuTTY.` Now, I'm aiming to replicate the same setup for the admin user `Ubuntu`.

I've followed the directions outlined in these two resources: [Arch Linux Forum](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240729) and [Blog](https://dhole.github.io/post/pulseaudio_multiple_users/), yet I’ve run into some problems.

### Here's what I've attempted:

- Appended the following lines to `/etc/pulse/client.conf`

```yaml
   autospawn = no
   default-server = unix:/tmp/riri-pulse-socket
   enable-memfd = yes
```

- Replaced `load-module module-native-protocol-unix` with `load-module module-native-protocol-unix auth-anonymous=1 socket=/tmp/riri-pulse-socket` in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`
- Executed `pulseaudio --kill` for both users, followed by `pulseaudio --start`

---

However, when I run `pulseaudio --start`, I receive the following error:

```yaml
$ pulseaudio --start
n: [pulseaudio] main.c: user-configured server at unix:/tmp/riri-pulse-socket, refusing to start/autospawn.
```

On inspecting `/tmp`, I found no trace of `riri-pulse-socket`

So I tried to resolve it by setting `autospawn = yes`, but the error remained unresolved.

However, I discovered a potential solution online suggesting the use of `pulseaudio -D`. Upon trying this, I observed that it successfully created the socket in `/tmp` without any errors.

```yaml
$ ls -l /tmp/riri-pulse-socket
srwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu 0 Jan 29 03:08 /tmp/riri-pulse-socket
```

[Curious that the socket is shown as 0 bytes. Is this typical?]

---

Following the adjustments, the audio still remains non-functional for `ubuntu` (both `RDP` and `PuTTY`), and surprisingly, even the previously working `windowsxp`

Reverting the modifications indeed brings me back to square one, where the audio is functional solely for `windowsxp`, but not for `ubuntu`.

### Note:

*I modified the files in* `/etc/pulse` *as* `pulseaudio` *wasn’t recognizing local configurations and wasn’t creating the socket in* `/tmp` *for whatever reason.*

*I’ve confirmed that* `pulseaudio` *is operating in user mode, and not system mode by observing the processes in* `htop`, *which displays the username instead of* `root` *or* `pulse`.

### Logs:

```yaml
$ pulseaudio --start -vvv
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: Parsing configuration file '/etc/pulse/client.conf'
D: [pulseaudio] conf-parser.c: Failed to open configuration file '/etc/pulse/client.conf.d/01-enable-autospawn.conf': No such file or directory
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at unix:/tmp/riri-pulse-socket, refusing to start/autospawn.
```

```py
$ systemctl --user status pulseaudio
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-01-29 05:43:33 JST; 36s ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 3189 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 1660)
     Memory: 1.8M
        CPU: 171ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1002.slice/user@1002.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─3189 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

Jan 29 05:43:33 ubuntu pulseaudio[3189]: Build library version 15.99.0
Jan 29 05:43:33 ubuntu pulseaudio[3189]: sink_process_msg: not running
Jan 29 05:43:33 ubuntu pulseaudio[3189]: close_send:
Jan 29 05:43:33 ubuntu pulseaudio[3189]: Build library version 15.99.0
Jan 29 05:43:33 ubuntu systemd[2150]: Started Sound Service.
Jan 29 05:44:08 ubuntu pulseaudio[3189]: sink_process_msg: not running
Jan 29 05:44:08 ubuntu pulseaudio[3189]: close_send:
Jan 29 05:44:08 ubuntu pulseaudio[3189]: Connected ok fd 29
Jan 29 05:44:08 ubuntu pulseaudio[3189]: sink_process_msg: not running
Jan 29 05:44:08 ubuntu pulseaudio[3189]: close_send:
```

Is it possible that the `sink_process_msg: not running` message is hinting at the problem?

#### Edit:

I came across this [discussion](https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/147730) and [topic](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240729) where they mention `PULSE_SCRIPT`, `PULSE_SERVER`, `pactl`, and `XDG`. However, I’m finding it challenging to comprehend their meaning and application.

Comment: riri is the name of someone in that linked topic. Have you tried replacing it with one of the two usernames?

Comment: Does this solution work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210859/10477326

Comment: Yes, I tried swapping `riri` with the two different usernames, but it didn't seem to make any difference. I'm not sure the socket name is relevant, is it?

Comment: No, the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68210859/10477326) didn't work for me. I think it switches `pulseaudio` to run in system mode, doesn't it? Regardless, I didn't get any sound output from either user.