# Possible to Play Audio through SSH Using PuTTY without Opening an RDP Session?

Tags: ssh, pulseaudio, rdp

I recently posted a question regarding an issue with setting up [PulseAudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1501635/issue-with-pulseaudio-when-configuring-for-multiple-users-ubuntu-22-04). I have since encountered a related problem that I believe might help resolve the original issue.

I am currently using PuTTY to `SSH` into my Ubuntu machine and have noticed that audio does not play through PuTTY over `SSH`, despite having PulseAudio installed.

Interestingly, however, audio playback works as expected when I use `RDP` via Remote Desktop Connection. Additionally, if there’s an open `RDP` session associated with the same user, audio is also able to play through PuTTY.

My question is, is there a way to configure the system to allow audio playback through `SSH` using PuTTY without the need to open an `RDP` session?

Could this be achieved through something like `port forwarding` or firing up any necessary PulseAudio files that are typically opened when starting `RDP` but not `SSH`? Or is it necessary to have an `RDP` session open, given that its protocol might be the one directly enabling the audio playback, and SSH is merely just piggybacking off of it?

### Edit:

The website's asking me to specify how my question differs from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371687). The referenced question pertains to playing audio via `SSH` with `X11 forwarding`, an approach I've attempted without success.

My objective, however, is to have the audio play directly from the `SSH` terminal, similar to the functionality of `RDP`, without necessitating the opening of any additional GUI window.

Comment: I'm curious why some people capitalize every word in their question, can you shed some light?

Comment: It's called Title Case.  Except I would have spelled it "through" and "without", as they are prepositions. @thomasrutter .  I prefer it, tbh.

Comment: Hey, what sounds are you expecting when you connect over SSH?  SSH/TTY is text-based, so what are you actually trying to do or hear?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to carry audio over SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371687/how-to-carry-audio-over-ssh)

Comment: @earthmeLon Sorry for the delay! I'm using `mpv` to play audio while watching a video in the terminal using `--vo=tct` or when playing an audio file.

Comment: @DanielT Nope! I did everything as described but I still don’t get any sound unless I have an `RDP` session open in the background.